# Ping then DNS lookup before I purge an asset

Tags: powershell

So I am trying to Purge IPs from tool that we use. Before I can purge the assets we need to make sure the host is not pingable and not in DNS. I am new to PS and cant seem to wrap my head around on doing this. Any help is greatly appreciated. I have been doing this as a manual process by pinging the list of IPs and hostnames and doing a nslookup in cmd prompt before selecting the IPs that are needing to be removed. I have about 13k IPs left to do.

Update:
I want to implement this portion into it. Where In cell A it will have the IP
cell B will let me know if it is up or down. And Cell D will let me know if it is DNS aswell. Below is the script I got for pinging and checking if up or down and checking AD to see if the hostname is still in AD. I want it similar to this.. Please excuse my english

```
$path = ".\results.xls"

$objExcel = new-object -comobject excel.application 

if (Test-Path $path) 
{ 
$objWorkbook = $objExcel.WorkBooks.Open($path) 
$objWorksheet = $objWorkbook.Worksheets.Item(1) 
}

else { 
$objWorkbook = $objExcel.Workbooks.Add() 
$objWorksheet = $objWorkbook.Worksheets.Item(1)
}

$objExcel.Visible = $True

#########Add Header####

$objWorksheet.Cells.Item(1, 1) = "HostName"
$objWorksheet.Cells.Item(1, 2) = "Result"
$objWorksheet.Cells.Item(1, 3) = "MachineIP"
$objWorksheet.Cells.Item(1, 4) = "Active Directory"

$machines = Get-Content .\machinelist.txt

$row=2

$machines | foreach-object{
$ping = $null
$iname = $null
$machine = $_
$ping = Test-Connection $machine -Count 1 -ea silentlycontinue
$checkAD = try {$comp = Get-ADComputer -Identity $machine -ErrorAction 
Stop
if ($comp){"Yes"}else{throw}
}
catch {"No"}

$objWorksheet.Cells.Item($row,4) = $checkAD

if($ping){

$objWorksheet.Cells.Item($row,1) = $machine
$objWorksheet.Cells.Item($row,2) = "UP"

$iname = $ping.IPV4Address.IPAddressToString

$objWorksheet.Cells.Item($row,3) = $iname

$row++}
else {

$objWorksheet.Cells.Item($row,1) = $machine
$objWorksheet.Cells.Item($row,2) = "DOWN"

$row++}
}
```

Comment: What does your list of assets look like - is it a delimited text file or SQL table? How do you plan to purge the asset?

Comment: My team mate will do an API call with a list of IPs that are needing to be purged. after we find out what IPs are good to purge.

Comment: Looks like you've tried `Test-Connection` and `Get-ADComputer`. What were your results?

Comment: We thought pinging and checking AD would be a good start for purging, but it doesnt help us for our RHEL and Mac systems

Answer (score 0):

Here's a start, using [Test-Connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/test-connection?view=powershell-6) and [Resolve-DnsName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/dnsclient/resolve-dnsname?view=win10-ps), assuming you have a list of hosts' IP and name separated by a space, with a carriage return between each host:

```
$Assets = @"
127.0.0.1 localhost
255.255.255.255 fakehost
"@
$FailedPing = @()
$NoDNS = @()
$Assets -split "`r" | %{
    $ipaddress = ($_.split(' ')[0]).trim() 
    $hostName = ($_.split(' ')[1]).trim()
    Write-Host "IP: $ipaddress HOST: $hostName " 
    Try {
        Test-Connection -ComputerName $ipaddress -Count 2 -ErrorAction Stop | Out-Null
    }Catch {
        $FailedPing += [pscustomobject]@{IP=$ipaddress; HostName = $hostName}
    }
    Try {
        Resolve-DnsName -Name $hostName -ErrorAction Stop |  Out-Null
    }Catch {
        $NoDNS += [pscustomobject]@{HostName = $hostName;Problem = $Error[0].Exception}
    }

}
$FailedPing | ft 
$NoDNS | ft
```

Comment: I made an update to my post above. Do you thnk I can do that way. Sorry for my english